# Error while doing truffle init. EDIT: Truffle isn't working itself

Tags: truffle

I am getting the following error while doing truffle init. I have followed the steps here: [image]

https://medium.com/@merunasgrincalaitis/the-ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-and-deploy-a-fully-descentralized-dapp-in-ethereum-18f0cf6d7e0e

When I get to truffle init, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:60353
!function(e,a){ true?module.exports=a():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("ganache",[],a):"object"==typeof exports?exports.ganache=a():e.ganache=a()}(global,function(){return function(e){var a={};function t(c){if(a[c])return a[c].exports;var n=a[c]={i:c,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[c].call(n.exports,n,n.exports,t),n.l=!0,n.exports}return t.m=e,t.c=a,t.d=function(e,a,c){t.o(e,a)||Object.defineProperty(e,a,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:c})},t.r=function(e){Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},t.n=function(e){var a=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return t.d(a,"a",a),a},t.o=function(e,a){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,a)},t.p="",t.w={},t(t.s=1036)}([function(e,a,t){try{var c=t(1);if("function"!=typeof c.inherits)throw"";e.exports=c.inherits}catch(a){e.exports=t(1021)}},function(e,a){e.exports=__webpack_require__(3)},function(e,a,t){"use strict";var c="function"==typeof Symbol

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

**EDIT**
While using truffle, truffle init, truffle unbox webpack, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RESOLVED:**

If you are encountering the same error, please check that your node is updated to the latest version. My node was updated to 6.11.3 while the LTS was 8.

[Download Here](https://nodejs.org/en/)

[Release Schedule Here (LTS)](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/)

You can check node version using

```
node -v
```

and npm version using

```
npm -v
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to "bypass" this issue would be using a boilerplate from [here](https://truffleframework.com/boxes/), with regards to the tutorial doing `truffle unbox webpack` would probably be the best prerequisite for what the tutorial is explaining. For everything front end related, you could then basically just edit everything according to your tutorials' needs.

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt really understand what to do exactly. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `truffle init` is suppose to create a very very minimalistic boilerplate the tutorial tells you to enhance. `truffle unbox webpack` initiates a more elaborate boilerplate, which already has many of the things from the tutorial in place. Then instead of creating all these components, you can just edit them if you wish to follow along the tutorial.

Comment: Nikita I feel my truffle only is not working! I tried doing truffle unbox webpack and it still gives me the same error. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: I feel I know what the problem is. The syntax error is occurring because of uneven number of opening and closing brackets. I am sure this is an unusual request but can you send me your 60353th line of your cli.bundled.js because that is where the rror is.

Comment: Well, not sure if that will help, but here you go. https://www55.zippyshare.com/v/vcXAwB9l/file.html
I would recommend a clean reinstall of truffle, though.

Comment: Thanks @Nikita Fuchs but I solved the issue. It was with my mac not downloading truffle properly because of node not being updated!